# How does NP-completess of decision problems relate to NP-completeness of search problems?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, search-problem

### Background

Oded Goldreich differentiates in his textbook (*[Computational Complexity: A Conceptual Perspective](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/1373317)*) between the "decision" variant of NP problems and "search" variant of NP problems, denoted using binary relations between "instance" and "solution":

> Call a binary relation $R$ an *NP relation* if
>
> - $(x,y)\in R \implies |y|\leq q(|x|)$ for some polynomial $q$, i.e., solutions are only polynomially longer, and
> - $R\in \mathrm{P}$, i.e, it can be efficiently checked if $y$ is a solution to $x$.
>
> [Goldreich denotes the class of all NP relations as $\mathcal{PC}$, p. 49, Def. 2.3]

Similar to many-one-reductions between sets, Goldreich defines a Levin-reduction between NP relations:

> $R$ *Levin-reduces* to $R'$ when there are two p-computable functions $f,g$ such that
>
> 1. $f$ many-one-reduces from $S_R = \{ x\mid \exists y. (x,y)\in R\}$ to $S_{R'}=\{x'\mid \exists y'.(x',y')\in R'\}$, and
> 2. $g$ translates solutions for $f(x)$ back into solutions for $x$, i.e., $(f(x), y')\in R' \implies (x, g(x, y'))\in R$.

As usual, we can now define NP-complete sets with respect to many-one-reductions, and NP-complete *relations  with respect to Levin-reductions* (that is a NP relation $R$ such that every NP relation $Q$ can be Levin-reduced to $R$).

It is immediately clear that Levin-completeness is stronger than many-one-completeness: given a Levin-complete relation $R$, the corresponding decision variant $S_R = \{ x\mid \exists y. (x,y)\in R\}$ is many-one-complete. Also, there exist problems that are both Levin-complete and many-one-complete, e.g. SAT and the natural search variant $\mathit{SATR}=\{(\varphi, w) \mid w$ satisfies formula $\varphi\}$.

However, I am unsure if Levin-completeness and many-one-completeness are equally strong, in particular if many-one-completeness (of a relation's decision variant) implies Levin-completness.

### Question

Does the following statement hold for all NP relations $R$?

> **the set $S_R=\{x\mid \exists y. (x,y)\in R\}$ is many-one-complete $\Rightarrow$ the relation $R$ is Levin-complete. (*)**

I am tending towards a negative answer, and presume that under certain (cryptographic hardness) assumptions the statement (*) should fail to hold. However, I was unable to construct appropriate counterexamples when, e.g., assuming that one-way functions exist. **Under which assumptions does the statement (*) hold/fail to hold?**

Note that it can be showed that the statement (*) holds when asuming the hypothesis Q by [Fenner et al. (2003)](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0890-5401(03)00119-6). Conversely, when assuming $\neg$Q, one can show the weaker statement that there exists an NP relation $R$ (with $S_R=$SAT) such that the standard relation for SAT $\mathrm{SATR}$ does not Levin-reduce to $R$ *if we insist that the reduction function $f$ (in 1.) is the identity function*.